# PHP Youtube Video displaying on page with database

Tags: php, video, youtube

I'm making "Social Network" and i want to be able to display youtube video when user put in Youtube Link and some description, just like on Facebook.
I managed to make when user put link it display video from database, but i can't figure out how to not show video when user don't put link and I want to show Youtube video when user put a link and description and send it to database.
Can anyone help?

**Update**

```
if(preg_match("/youtube.com(.+)v=([^&]+)/", $url)) {
  preg_match("/v=([^&]+)/", $url, $matches);
  if(isset($matches[1])) {
    $test = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1];
  }
}
```

I've found this , this grabs everything i need , but when i type like: "link" and some text,

How can i stop taking all after link???

Comment: I wanted to edit to make it more clear but I can't even understand because the sentence is not finished: "but when i type like: "link" and some text, "

Comment: Ok,  imagine you are on Facebook,  and u paste link and text after link,  same here,  but when i paste a link and text my code doesn't work,  but when i type text first and than link it works,  i want to be able to paste link and text after,  check my pregmatch

Comment: I've made it,  everything is working now,  thanks anyway.